# set interval of date

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm going to make a form in which the user can specify a fill time period (first date and second date, in the code). I use ....
My problem is that if I select a date in one field, then it is automatically substituted in the second. How can I fix this error?
If my approach to solving a given problem is not optimal, I can listen to advice.

```
  .....
          TextField(
        controller: dateinput, //editing controller of this TextField
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
            icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today), //icon of text field
            labelText: "Enter first Date" //label text of field
        ),
        readOnly: true,  //set it true, so that user will not able to edit text
        onTap: () async {
          DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
              context: context, initialDate: DateTime.now(),
              firstDate: DateTime(2000), //DateTime.now() - not to allow to choose before today.
              lastDate: DateTime(2101)
          );

          if(pickedDate != null ){
            print(pickedDate);  //pickedDate output format => 2021-03-10 00:00:00.000
            String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(pickedDate);
            print(formattedDate); //formatted date output using intl package =>  2021-03-16
            //you can implement different kind of Date Format here according to your requirement

            setState(() {
              dateinput.text = formattedDate; //set output date to TextField value.
            });
          }else{
            print("Date is not selected");
          }
        },
      ),


      TextField(
        controller: dateinput, //editing controller of this TextField
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today), //icon of text field
            labelText: "Enter second Date" //label text of field
        ),
        readOnly: true,  //set it true, so that user will not able to edit text
        onTap: () async {
          DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
              context: context, initialDate: DateTime.now(),
              firstDate: DateTime(2000), //DateTime.now() - not to allow to choose before today.
              lastDate: DateTime(2101)
          );

          if(pickedDate != null ){
            print(pickedDate);  //pickedDate output format => 2021-03-10 00:00:00.000
            String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(pickedDate);
            print(formattedDate); //formatted date output using intl package =>  2021-03-16
            //you can implement different kind of Date Format here according to your requirement

            setState(() {
              dateinput.text = formattedDate; //set output date to TextField value.
            });
          }else{
            print("Date is not selected");
          }
        },
      ),
 ......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the same controller for each TextField....use unique controllers.